# Should I flag poll questions or is vote to close enough?

Tags: discussion, flags

I recently ran across a couple of open poll/subjective questions.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945904/what-are-your-most-useful-own-library-extensions

[Best Practices for Concurrent CRM 2011 Development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862705/best-practices-for-concurrent-crm-2011-development)

My understanding is that questions of this nature are typically closed pretty rapidly. But these questions weren't. My guess is they had low views because they don't contain popular tags.

Normally I would just vote to close poll questions, but I flagged them as "Poll Question" because I felt that due to the low views and the lack of incentive to find questions to vote to close they wouldn't be closed organically.

**So was I correct to flag these poll questions or should I just voted to close and let well enough alone?**

---

**Update/Warning for seekers of Deputy and Marshall badges**

Of the 11 questions I flagged "Poll Question" since asking this question only 2 were actually closed and one was actually declined. This is sending a signal to me that at best this flagging is borderline. At worst this is simply invalid.

Also I also suspect that the only reason why I didn't get 8 declined was because the mod took pity on me so its probably not safe to think that 10 of the 11 flags were valid.

Comment: Dunno what you're talking about.  They're both closed as not constructive.

Comment: Yay my Flag weight went up a couple of 10ths of a point. So does this mean I should indeed flag open poll questions, or did I just get lucky that Bill and Will agreed with me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If they're brand new (less than one hour) then a vote to close should be enough.  If they're older than that and they don't seem to have enough close velocity it's okay to flag them.  The rule of thumb that I usually apply is that if the OP is asking for a list where all answers are equally valid, then it's a poll and should be closed.

Comment: Well that's good enough for me. just flagged 6 more ;)

Comment: @Conrad: I remember hating the "Favorite Programming Fonts" one back when it was new.  Thanks for bringing it up.  :)