# Ban certain phrases in the other box for flagging

Tags: feature-request, 10k-tools

It is very confusing when perusing the Tools menu and looking at flags to see the reason as

- not constructive
- off topic
- off topic; belongs on Super User
- not a real question

The other box should not be used to input *close* reasons. Especially since I cannot select

- not constructive
- off topic
- off topic; belongs on Super User
- not a real question

as a flag reason. So what is one to do? If you put that same text into the other box as part of your *concur* flag, then you may get a message back from the Moderators like this:

> "declined - You don't need to repeat Community flags. We see them."

The ***flagging*** reason does not show it as a ***close*** reason since the Close Question box may have no close votes for that question or the close reason does not match the flag reason.

The entire process is very confusing.

Comment: These close reasons are flags from users which don't yet have the right to vote. They get the same dialog as a flag dialog. Custom flag reasons don't show up in the 10k list.

Comment: @Paulo: Sounds like we have a disconnect then!

Answer (score 5):

I think this is more of a behavioral problem, mostly mine.  I didn't think it was necessary to bump the [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) user's flags to the top of the mod queue, since those are almost never urgent.  I should have realized that non-moderators can't see whose flag they're concurring with, so there's no way I could reasonably expect you to know those were Community flags.  Keep flagging as you were, and I'll try to stop being a bonehead.  Sorry about dropping your flag weight.

---

No actual change to the system should really be necessary, but it might be helpful (mostly to diamond moderators) if either the Community user were revealed as the flagger to 10K users in the flagging panel, or if Community flags didn't show up there at all.

Comment: Thought the request was about people who have voted to close also flagging as the same reason they just close voted

Comment: @random: The question is a little confusing, but I processed the flag yesterday so I remember it.  He had copied the flag message from another flag in the /review panel and entered it as his own flag reason.  Close reason text should be fine to enter in as "other" text in the flag reason.

Comment: community user has a fixed flag weight; marking helpful or declined will have no effect on community user

Comment: @Jeff: I marked the flag as declined to leave feedback for 0A0D, not for the Community user.

Comment: @bill sure, just pointing out that nobody needs to be worried about community user's flag weight since it can't change

Answer (score 2):

> "declined - You don't need to repeat Community flags. We see them."

This should never happen, I have flagged (other reason -> copied/pasted reason) & voted to close question A LOT OF times. Everytime they were marked as helpful.

Do not worry about it and just flag them

Comment: Why did you need to flag with the same close reason?

Comment: @random: because it's closed faster and because there are these flags button(s) for purpose?

Comment: @random: It's not the close reason though, that's the problem.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment: no. When I'm voting to close I flag it.

Comment: Are you re-flagging posts from the [Community](http://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) user, or from other members of the community?  Because people piggy-backing off the Community flags to get an easy flag-weight boost is really unnecessary.  They're virtually guaranteed to be valid flags, but they're almost never so urgent that we need to address them *right now*.

Comment: @Bill: How do we know if it is a Community flag? Flags are anonymous to 10K users.

Comment: @0A0D They have fixed messages, like "Low answer quality score" or "More than 20 comments posted in the past 3 days"

Comment: @0A0D: Well now... that is an interesting point.  I'll just stop declining those.  Sorry about that.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: I have never flagged posts community flags - just "vandalism" few times when I was sure it IS vandalism

Comment: @BilltheLizard: wow, you're declining them all?

Comment: @Michael: Oh, well then that should be an answer to my question then and actually the fix should be to show Community or something so we know.

Comment: @genesis-φ No, I declined two of them yesterday or the day before.

Comment: @Bill: If only there were [something you could do](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105542/allow-moderators-to-reverse-and-or-nullify-flag-decisions). :)