# Is this post really an answer?

Tags: discussion, flags

I flagged [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2794576/507519) as "Not an answer" since, well, it does not answer the question but is merely commenting on the merits (or lack thereof) of the framework the poster of the question is using. In my opinion, this post should be a comment and not an answer.

Yet the flag was declined by a moderator. I guess it was bound to happen some time, but I can't really see *why* in this case. What did I do wrong - except, perhaps, for not offering a better explanation using the "Other" flag?

Comment: I feel like I've seen a few posts like this recently, and I know I've had some flags declined lately that I thought were obviously valid (i.e. not borderline cases). I'm guessing that it's because of the recent mod election. Maybe the new mods haven't quite learned the standards yet, or they're applying slightly different -- not better or worse, just different -- standards than the old mods, or both.

Comment: @PopularDemand: I can't speak for the other mods, but I will defer to the "getting over the hump" part of my nomination bid.  I'm doing my best to get better at this ASAP and again, I apologize if my actions have had a negative impact on you or anyone else on SO; any actions that have been deemed incorrect have been reversed to the best of my ability.

Comment: No worries, @casperOne. If anything, it's surprising this didn't happen sooner, with the volume of flags you guys reportedly have to sift through. And as always, I appreciate the transparency/responsibility on y'all's part.

Comment: @casperOne: I think that anyone that bothers to review posts, let alone be a moderator, is (or should be) grown up enough to realize that differences in opinion, or even the occasional mistake, will happen and that no ill is intended. So you can stop apologizing and keep up the good work :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was the one who declined the flag.

In retrospect, it was a mistake on my part (I misinterpreted the answer in relation to the question), and the answer has been deleted.

I apologize for the impact on your flag weight that this has had.

Comment: @thkala Also, unfortunately we can't reverse flag decisions. Please help change that by showing your support here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105542/allow-moderators-to-reverse-and-or-nullify-flag-decisions

Comment: I appreciate your answer and don't worry about my flag weight - I'll get it back :-)