# Should I flag answers that would be comments, were it not for the 50 rep. requirement?

Tags: discussion, comments, flags

So, I believe the policy is that things should only be flagged as "not an answer" when they are completely irrelevant, or are things like "thanks", "me too", etc.

So, then, should I flag [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8527085/27727) by [cur4so](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1072222/cur4so):

> looks like the same issue I had some time ago. Hopefully,
>   [check that a task is completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373318/check-that-a-task-is-completed/8373346#8373346)
>   you will find useful  P.S. I'd post it as a comment rather than an
>   answer but I don't have enough privileges to comment

I'd guess “yes”, but if we're [going to have a 50 rep. requirement to post comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12119/lower-the-amount-of-reputation-needed-to-comment), it doesn't seem like a good use of diamond-moderators' time to work around it.

Comment: Well, it's also not an answer because it only provides a link. So it should be flagged anyways. As far as I know, moderators only convert to comments if the user can do so anyways. Otherwise it just gets deleted.

Comment: @animuson: That's not the impression I get from reading http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115797/why-are-more-flags-on-answers-getting-declined-nowadays

Comment: I flag things with a comment "Just a link." all the time. As long as you have given them a chance to improve the answer *from* being just a link (usually I give ~15 hours), the moderators *will* delete it. That specific example is not even a link, [try reading this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/72002/141525). This specific example *does not include any details* about the actual answer in the post.

Comment: `but I don't have enough privileges to comment` -- apparently for a good reason.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd say yes you should. If it's not an answer, flag it as such. Regardless of **why** the user decided to post a non-answer as an answer, it's still not an answer and should be converted/deleted.

Comment: Plus, we can convert comments posted as answers by users with less than 50 rep into actual comments.

Answer (score -3):

I'd call that an answer, just a bad one.  Downvoting and/or commenting is probably your best course of action.